# Binding text property of text box to variable defined on MainWindow-WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm newbie on WPF and I have text box and button which open folder browser dialog.
When the user select folder I would like text box will contain the selected path. 
So on MainWindow I added two variables:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public string outputFolderPath { get; set; }
    string reducedModelFolderPath { get; set; }
}
```

and when user selected folder path (after open folder dialog) I updated those variables by doing (for example):

```
outputFolderPath = dialog.SelectedPath
```

In MainWindow.xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="outputFolder" Width ="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 10">
```

How can I bind TextBox.Text to outputFolderPath variable?
Thanks for your assitance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set DataContext of your window to *this*, to access your property in XAML, and after that bind to the property. As you are binding not to DependencyProperty, you should notify your binding that property has changed, which could be done by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface in your Window. 
I've provided sample code to show the concept.
But this is very ugly, much better to use MVVM pattern instead.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string outputFolderPath { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;           
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        outputFolderPath = "Some data";
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(outputFolderPath)));
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="simplest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:simplest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Go" />   
        <TextBox x:Name="outputFolder" Width ="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="5 10" Text="{Binding outputFolderPath}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much! 
Can you explain regarding "much better to use MVVM pattern instead"

Comment: Can I use the same PropertyChangedEventHandler to more than one variable?

Comment: According to MVVM, which stands for Model-View-ViewModel, you should not have logic in your Window.xaml.cs, all actions are to be done in ViewModel, that is separate class, that implements INotifyPropertyChanged interface and is assigned to the DataContext property of the View (Window in our case). An article that explains that consept: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained

Comment: You may use the same PropertyChanged event for all properties in your Window, simply providing their names when triggerint the event. PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(<Any other propery>)));

Comment: It doesn't work for me! I tried doing PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ModelFolderPath))); which  ModelFolderPath is different variable and the binding doesn't work!

Comment: Is ModelFolderPath a public property? For example reducedModelFolderPath from the code you've provided will not work, because it is not public. Also, you can take a look at Output tab of Visual Studio, all binding errors are output there.

Comment: Thanks! it's working fine! why the variable must be declare as public?

Comment: NP) It has to be public in order to follow Incapsulation principle of OOP, I suppose. Typically you don't want to expose non-public properties of a class.